# Postfix / Dovecot / MySQL / Ubuntu 16.04 - Receiving via IMAP, but not sending

Tags: email, postfix, mail, smtp, dovecot

I've reached the point where I think I've read every post/article on this and am stuck. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, and Linux in general, but I've been trying to tackle one problem at a time.

The problem right now is it will not send email from an external email client. I've tried linking it through gmail, through my outlook app. It will receive emails no problem, indicating that the inbound server is working fine.

At this point it also does not generate any errors in the mail.err file.

Here is an excerpt of the mail.log file.

```
Sep 15 01:34:12 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/qmgr[9953]: F02FF1F8F98: from=
<nate@exampledomain.com>, size=2312, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 15 01:34:12 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9963]: connect to gmail-
smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep 15 01:34:42 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9963]: connect to gmail-
smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
Sep 15 01:34:42 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9963]: connect to 
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1b]:25: Network is 
unreachable
Sep 15 01:34:42 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9989]: connect to 
aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.207.27]:25: Connection timed out
Sep 15 01:34:42 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9989]: connect to 
aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c0c::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Sep 15 01:34:42 lamp-512mb-nyc3-01 postfix/smtp[9989]: connect to 
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
```

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors?

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/Example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like outgoing connections on port 25 are blocked by a firewall. Run `telnet gmail-
smtp-in.l.google.com 25` to manually establish a connection to some SMTP server (and also try other destination hosts, in case only google would be targeted).

If the connection works, you should receive some output similar to this:

```
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c06::1b...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP q18si2099858wre.148 - gsmtp
```

If you also receive connection timeouts with `telnet`, check your system for local firewalls and contact your network administrator/operator to open outgoing connections on port 25 in his firewall. If you're operating the server behind some commodity router: some also block connection attempts on port 25, consult the router configuration or manual in this case (but be aware most recipient sites will block mails from non-static IP addresses to fight spam, use a smarthost in this case to send mail).

Comment: Thank you so much! It was indeed blocked-- which sounds so obvious. Rather than checking ufw to see what ports were allowed, I had previously just set it to allow 25. When I checked I saw that it both allowed 25, but also had a rule to deny 25 out... which was solved by sudo ufw allow out 25. Thank you again!